# Where to place the C# code for checking internet connection in App.xaml.cs #Windows phone 8.1 Development?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm a starter in developing windows phone 8.1 apps.
In my app, the first page has to check the internet connection if true it should navigate to next page otherwise app should close.
I'm having troubles with how to add code.
Please help me...!

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, you might want to check out parts of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) on what types of questions are best for a Q&A site. Yours is pretty broad and doesn't show effort so it will likely get down-voted and/or closed. Though don't let that dissuade you from using the site as a great resource when you come back with more specific questions.

Comment: Don't do this: "otherwise app should close". This will only annoy your user, since he doesn't know why the app closed. If it is required, show an error.

Comment: Okay, I will show the error.Help me about remaining part...

Comment: Put the code in the app.cs code-behind for the OnStarup or application launched event event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft requirements are that your app starts (leaves the splash screen) within 10 seconds.  You should do all the minimal loading your app requires during the start-up process, then do the internet checking after the program has loaded.  You can show a spinner or the floating dots image, if you'd like to inform the user that they need to wait for your app to do something.